# Simple Article usage question implied or not?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

> It doesn't matter if you are a nurse or a doctor, you still need a pass.

In this sentence, can I skip article a just before doctor?

> It doesn't matter if you are a nurse or doctor, you still need a pass.

Is the article implied in the second example or must I always include an article?

Comment: Yes, including the article avoids confusion. A snake and a serpent are not always alike.